# 400 Bad Request HttpClient Mtls Certificate C#

Tags: c#, x509certificate, mtls

Im receiving 400 bad request from the endPoint. I can see the cert loaded in httpClientHandler and then in httpclient, but it doest work.

public HttpClientHandler generateCert()
{

```
        var SignatureCertificateThumbprint = "8f375e9024722edca43913dc267956b00ed36f2b";
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

        string certThumb = SignatureCertificateThumbprint.ToUpperInvariant();
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        IEnumerable<X509Certificate2> certificates = store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>();
        X509Certificate currentCert = certificates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Thumbprint == certThumb);

        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(currentCert);
        httpClientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
        httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => { return true; };
        store.Close();
        
        return httpClientHandler;
    }

   


    public async Task<object> PostEndPoint(object dataObject, string url)
    {
        EndPointBearerTokenResponse onAuth = (EndPointBearerTokenResponse)GetAuthorizeToken().Result;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataObject);
        StringContent data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => { return true; };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(generateCert());
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { NoCache = true };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", onAuth.access_token);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);}
```

I can use the endPoint from PostMan but not from app.
Tnx for help. Regards

Comment: What is the point to use two authentication methods in same request? I see, you use JWT and client certificate authentication, this barely makes any sense. In addition, I suspect that there are problems with your certificate. It may not have private key and/or your app doesn't have permissions to access it, since it is installed in local machine cert store.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the private key into the cert generating a new file with both .cert and .key

Comment: Hi, please consider adding more details as to how this helps solve the question. The more detail you can add the more helpful your answer will be to other's. Please consider reviewing the how to answer article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).